# Ruby - Pass a string from controller to view with spaces

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I am attempting to send a string variable from the controller to the view using an instance variable. The issue is that when the view is rendered the string variable that is sent is stripped of all spaces that were in the original string. Is there some special property of ruby strings or how rails handles them that I'm missing?

Ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-linux] 
Rails 4.0.5

## Controller

```
def stringsub
  forminput = params['mystring']
  spaceinput = String.new(forminput)
  puts "Displaying @formstring from controller: " + @formstring
  @formstring = spaceinput
end
```

## View

```
<!--HTML page view -->
<p><%= @formstring %></p>
```

## Rails Terminal

```
Started POST "/pages/stringsub" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-04 19:34:26 -0500
Processing by PagesController#stringsub as HTML
Parameters: {"mystring"=>"this should have spaces"}
Displaying @formstring from controller: this should have spaces
Rendered pages/stringsub.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

## Rendered HTML

```
<!--HTML page view -->
<p>thisshouldhavespaces</p>
```

(note the spaces were removed in the final HTML)

Is there a way to preserve the spaces in the original string that is sent?

## Edit:

The issue was a method  created by a group member of this project whose method had the original string passed to it as a parameter and it used .gsub to remove spaces from the parameter sent to it.

## Method that broke it

```
def groupmethod(start)
    sub = start.split(" ")
    count = (start.length - start.gsub!(/\s+/, "").length + 1) * 0.4
```

Ironically I was actually able to fix it by creating a new variable out of it with String.new and passing that to the method instead

## Undamaged instance variable

```
forminput = params['mystring']
@formstring = forminput
testvariable = String.new(forminput)
groupmethod(testvariable)
```

Is there a better or more correct way of passing variables to ruby methods and use them separately without affecting the variable you passed to the method?

Comment: A single space should be preserved. multiple, no, because that's how HTML works, you'd need to make them non-.breaking

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no reason to use String.new or the temp variable.

Comment: Try putting `@formstring.freeze` in the controller to see if it’s being modified inadvertently anywhere.

Comment: `String#gsub!` modifies a string in-place, whereas `String#gsub` copies the original string and then modifies the copy. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-gsub-21

Comment: Copy the string. In any case, questions shouldn't have answers; post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stringsub` method can be simplified.  Let's say you have a `new` action in your `UsersController` (simplified version):

```
def new
  set_str
end

private

def set_str
  @str = params['str']
  puts "@str: #{@str}"
end
```

The instance variable `@str` should be available to your view.  Make sure the instance variable giving you trouble isn't being modified elsewhere in your application. Single spaces will be preserved, but if you want to preserve all whitespace you could style your element with `.your-class { white-space: pre; }`

As an aside (in your original method), I don't see how the `puts` line outputs anything for `@forminput` when (apparently) it gets initialized at the very end.